# Business Objects - Oracle binary double data type

Tags: types, oracle11g, business-objects

I would like use **Business Objects** (XI 3.1 SP2) with scientist data and an **Oracle 11G** database. For a better accuracy on floating data, I use Oracle **binary double** datatype, but this datatype is not supported by Business Objects. WebI and Designer throw an exception (*Exception : CS, Non supported datatype*).

Does anyone has encountered this kind of problem, and if so found a solution?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a SQL statement you can add `to_number()` around the BINARY DOUBLE columns to convert them to a regular NUMBER before Business Objects reads them.  Or create a view that does the same thing and then select from the view.  (This assumes that you only need the extra accuracy in Oracle, not in Business Objects.)